# In ruby is "IO::SEEK_SET" a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ they dint mention SEEK as a method 
but in the following program they have used 'seek' as a method ?

```
input_file = ARGV[0]
def print_all(f)
  puts f.read()
end
def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_SET)
end
def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count} #{f.readline()}"
end
current_file = File.open(input_file)
puts "First let's print the whole file:"
puts # a blank line
print_all(current_file)
puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."
rewind(current_file)
puts "Let's print three lines:"
current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IO::SEEK_SET` is a constant. Things in all caps are usually constants in ruby

`::` can also be used for method calls but that's rather archaic and is being removed from ruby in 2.1 (if I recall correctly).